# OrderByDescending by child elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, automapper

I have two entities:

**Blog:**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
```

**Post:**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public DateTime Published { get; set; }
```

...and I have two view models:

**BlogVm:**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<PostVm> Posts { get; set; }
```

**PostVm:**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public DateTime Published { get; set; }
```

As you can see they are the same.

I would like to get only blogs with at **least 3 posts** and take only **3 newest posts**. Moreover, I would like to **OrderByDescending Post.Published.**

For mapping, I'm using AutoMapper.

I was trying something like this,s but the code does not work as I expected.

```
var blogs = _context.Blogs.Include(x => x.Posts)
                .Where(x.Posts.Count >= 4)
                .ProjectTo<BlogVm>()
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Posts.OrderByDescending(y => y.Published)).ToList();
```

I'm getting an error message:

> "System.ArgumentException: 'At least one object must implement
> IComparable.'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

at the moment you're asking it to order the `Blog`s by each blog's ordered posts, which... doesn't make sense. You could perhaps order the `Blog`s by their *most recent publish date*, and *separately* order each `Blog`'s `.Posts` by their publish date descending?

```
var blogs = _context.Blogs.Include(x => x.Posts)
                .Where(x.Posts.Count >= 4)
                .ProjectTo<BlogVm>()
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Posts.Max(y => y.Published)).ToList();

foreach(var blog in blogs) {
    blog.Posts.Sort((x,y) => y.Published.CompareTo(x.Published));
}
```

Comment: Why not something `quick`. `blogs.ForEach(x => x.Posts.Sort((y, z) => z.Date.CompareTo(y.Date)));`

Comment: @MUT k; now: in what objective way is that an improvement? IMO the `ForEach` method is hugely overused.

Answer (score 1):

You could try like this;

```
var blogs = _context.Blogs.Include(x => x.Posts)
    .Where(x.Posts.Count >= 4)
    .ProjectTo<BlogVm>()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Blog = x,
        //Take newly published 3 posts for per Blog
        RecentlyPosts = x.Posts.OrderByDescending(y => y.Published).Take(3)
    });
```

Also, it would be better to create a model class to select as known type instead of anonymous type.